# apache tutorial didn't work

Tags: networking, server, apache2, configuration

I followed the Apache2 Install and Configuration tutorial, but it doesn't seem to work.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview

I had no problem access my local website via http://localhost, and saw the index.html that I created. However, when I tried to configure new website via 000-default.conf (gci.conf) as shown on the tutorial - it didn't work! It pointed to some website that I didn't set on the conf file. Looks like it goes thru the DNS before the local server.

I appreciate very much if you could explain the reason, and possibly the solution for this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Apache does not rely on DNS, it simply directs traffic to the host that is reported in the HTTP header. Could you [edit] your question to include the virtual host configuration file? Are there multiple virtual host configuration files active, or just one?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed the tutorial to the teeth, ServerAdmin, DocumentRoot, ServerName - for two sites, www.SCL.com, www.SCL.net. I believe I found the answer (maybe); I need to modify the hosts file, /etc/hosts, to include these sites. Am I correct?

Comment: You should not need to edit your `/etc/hosts` file for the server unless you are trying to bypass global DNS. If you can [edit] your question to include the Apache virtual host configuration, I can double-check it for you. Can I confirm that you have *two* virtual host configuration files and both are active on your server?

Comment: Thank you; I don't know how to include the config file, so I gave up! I moved my files into html directory, and worked from there. Will come back to this problem, when I have some times. Thank you again very much.